# React js conditionally rendering a class to a specific mapped item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have been attempting to toggle a class on click so that when I click on one of the mapped items in my Tasks component, I add the 'complete' class and put a line through that item (crossing items off of a todo list). However with my current code set up, when I click on one element to add the class, all the other elements get crossed out as well and vice versa.

Here is my current setup.  The class 'complete' is what will add a line through one of the mapped items in the Tasks component.

```
import { Container, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const List = (props) =>{
    return(
    <div>
       <Link style={{textDecoration:'none'}} to={`/lists/${props.listId}`} > <p className="list-item">{props.item}</p></Link>
    </div>
    ) 
}

const Tasks = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div onClick={props.onClick} className={props.className} >
        <div className='task-item' >
             <p >{props.item}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default class Display extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.onCompletedTask = this.onCompletedTask.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            list: [],
            tasks:[],
            complete:false
        }
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps){
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/lists/${this.props.match.params.listId}`)
        .then(response =>{
            this.setState({
                tasks:response.data
            })
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){


        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/lists')
        .then(response=>{
            this.setState({
                list:response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        });


    }


    onCompletedTask(item){

        this.setState({ complete: !this.state.complete});
    }


    listCollection(){
        return(
         this.state.list.map(item=>{
             return(<List item = {item.title} listId={item._id} key = {item._id} />)

            })
        )
    }

    taskCollection(){
        return(
            this.state.tasks.map((item, index) =>{
                return(<Tasks onClick = {()=>this.onCompletedTask(item)} className={this.state.complete ? 'complete': ''} item={item.task}  key={index}/>)
            })
        )
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div id='main' >
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                    <div className="sidebar">
                        <h1 style={{fontSize:"25pt"}}>Lists</h1>
                        <div className="list-menu">
                           {this.listCollection()}
                        </div>
                        <form action='/new-list' method='GET'>
                            <div style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                            <button className='list-button' style={{fontSize:'12pt', borderRadius:'5px'}}>
                                + New List
                            </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className='tasks'>
                        <h1 style={{fontSize:'25pt'}}>Tasks</h1>
                        {this.taskCollection()}
                        <form action={`/lists/${this.props.match.params.listId}/new-task`} method='GET'>
                        <button className='task-button'>
                           +
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </Row>
                </Container>


            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state holds only a single completed value, which OFC toggle *all* tasks. You could instead store a map of completed tasks.

```
this.state = {
  list: [],
  tasks: [],
  complete: {}, // <--- use empty object as simple map object
}
```

Update `onCompletedTask` to store some uniquely identifying property of a task, like an `id` field

```
onCompletedTask(item){
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    completed: {
      ...prevState.completed, // <--- spread existing completed state
      [item.id]: !prevState.completed[item.id] // <--- toggle value
    },
  }));
}
```

Update. `taskCollection` to check the completed map by id

```
taskCollection = () => {
  const { completed, tasks } = this.state;
  return tasks.map((item, index) => (
    <Tasks
      onClick={() => this.onCompletedTask(item)}
      className={completed[item.id] ? "complete" : ""} // <--- check completed[item.id]
      item={item.task}
      key={index}
    />
  ))
};
```

[image: Edit strange-pascal-9m486]

Comment: Thank you for your help! So in the onCompletedTask() handler, I'm essentially pushing the item into the completed state object, and if the item is present in the state, it adds the class to it?

Comment: @saslam23 Not "pushing", but yes, that is the general idea. `completed` is a map, i.e. key-value pairs, so if the item's value in the map is truthy it adds the classname.